# Org chart CTE with exact index but plan shows expensive sort node

Tags: sql-server, cte, recursive, hierarchy

I've got a moderately large table (148 million rows) that's got pretty common org chart attributes to it.  Names are changed, but it's the same idea.  I was thinking of adding a hierarchyid column to the mix; then I could index that and hopefully make some of the queries faster.

This query is modeled on the msdocs sample on hierarchy id.  Before I ran it, I put indexes on (employeeid), (managerid, include employeeid), and (officeid, managerid, employeeid) hoping to make it as fast as possible.  But the query took over 5 hours to run.

I looked at the plan, and the (officeid, managerid, employeeid) index is used for both parts of the cte.

What I don't understand is that the ROW_NUMBER() windowing function also appears to have added a SORT node, which ss says is taking 94% of the query time.  It's already using an index that is pre-ordered in the same way, so why is there a SORT node taking up 94% of the time?

[image]

Thanks

```
WITH paths(path, duns, extended_gu, extended_parent)   
AS (  -- This section provides the value for the root of the hierarchy  
    SELECT hierarchyid::GetRoot() AS path, employeeid, officeid, managerid
    FROM OrgChart where officeid = 0

    -- This section provides values for all nodes except the root  
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT CAST(p.path.ToString() + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RD.officeid, RD.managerid 
    ORDER BY RD.officeid, RD.managerid) AS varchar(30)) + '/' AS hierarchyid),   
    RD.employeeid, RD.managerid, Rd.officeid
    FROM OrgChart rd   
    JOIN paths AS p ON rd.managerid = P.employeeid
) 
UPDATE rd set tree=P.Path
FROM Paths P
INNER JOIN  OrgChart rd on rd.duns = P.Duns
```

EDIT: Schema, added in response to comment below.  I don't see a "Paste The Plan" as a feature in the editor; where is that?  Rather than null on the roots, those ids are 0

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrgChart](
    [employeeid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [managerid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [officeid] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
    [tree] [hierarchyid] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [uixOrgChart_employeeids] ON [dbo].[OrgChart]
(
    [employeeid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [uixOrgChart_officemgremployee] ON [dbo].[OrgChart]
(
    [officeid] ASC,
    [managerid] ASC,
    [employeeid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [uixOrgChart_mgremp] ON [dbo].[OrgChart]
(
    [managerid] ASC
)
INCLUDE([employeeid]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to dba.SE.  To better answer your question, please provide the table definitions, and use something like Paste The Plan instead of pictures.  Also see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: [Pate The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) is a separate site. Upload your plan XML there and add the link to your question.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do ? Why do you need a rownumber ?
Couldn't you add it to the table before you do the recursive CTE ?
Itzik has a similar example but he has 
...
FROM PATHS 
JOIN OrgChart ...
https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/t-sql-queries/fundamentals-of-table-expressions-part-6-recursive-ctes

Comment: Thanks for all the replies...  The ROW_NUMBER() was just how the MS sample code for learning about the hierarchyid assigned tier level values for siblings when creating a hierarchyid data type for a tree structure.

I've never worked with the hierarchyid type before, but I thought if I could create one and then index it, that it would make "how many children are under this whole tree?" type queries faster.  But so far, it's pretty expensive to construct given the data as presented.

Comment: Thanks, Dan; I'll look at Paste The Plan...

Comment: Thanks, bbaird.  I was thinking the recursive clause was joining to the main clause by managerid, so as an experiment, I dropped the office id out of the ROW_NUMBER() window and just did PARTITION BY/ORDER BY managerid.

The sort dropped out of the plan but the query didn't seem hugely faster, at least for a couple of sample kicks.

Comment: [Eager Index Spools From Nonclustered Indexes](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/eager-index-spools-from-nonclustered-indexes/)

Comment: Can you provide some sample *before* and *after* data of what you're trying to accomplish, particularly with using `ROW_NUMBER()` to help calculate the `hierarchyid`? I'm almost wondering if you need to use a window function here at all or if you can simplify your code and eliminate the need for it, such as just by creating a dummy column called `RowNumber` that starts with a value of 1 in your base case of the **recursive CTE** and is incremented by 1 on each subsequent recursive case, for example. (But seeing some data examples will help me conceptualize how you may be able to rewrite it.)

Comment: Also I just saw Stephen Morris's comment (and your reply), and that's a good point as well. If you really do need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` then you may be able to precalculate it too before you hit your recursion. But based on your reply to his comment, I think you can just use a simple calculated integer value like my previous comment suggests. I'll post an answer once I see some sample data though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Erik's comment above was the most probative.

Creating a better index cut the time from 5 hours to a little over 3.

The other thing that made an even bigger difference was not updating columns on the main table; rather, I directed the hierarchy ids off into a normalized table instead.  That cut the time from a little over 3 to a little over 1

Comment: If 1 hour is sufficient for what you need, then you're good to go, woohoo! Otherwise, an FYI that I'm sure it's possible to cut that down to as little as a few seconds if not sub-second. (I'm not sure the size of your tables, but I've done recursive CTEs over hundreds of thousands of records in sub-second time, on modest hardware.) But doing so would require your current ***actual* execution plan** to be attached to your post, such as through [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).